# Checking array for unique digits and looping back

Tags: java, arrays, validation, loops

I am currently trying to write a program which asks the user for a three digit number and checks it against a random 3 digit number generate by the computer. The number the user enters must have three unique digits, as the computer number also has three unique digits.
So far I have managed to get the user's three digit number into an array with one digit in each array position, but I can't get it to validate properly. It is able to identify two digits being the same, so it would then need to ask the user for a new number that has 3 different digits (i.e. loop back to beginning) until such time as user complies. The System.out.println is just for me to check that it is picking out the double digits. Here is my code so far. This is a method, not the whole program.

```
public static int[] getUserNumberDebugMode(String compNum){
    final int RANDOM_NUMBER_SIZE = 3;
    int[]userNumber = new int [RANDOM_NUMBER_SIZE];

    String userGuessAsString;

    userGuessAsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(compNum + "\n Please enter a number.");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(userGuessAsString);

    // put three digit number individually into array
    for(int loop = (userNumber.length - 1); loop>=0; loop--){
        userNumber[loop]= number%10;
        number = number/10;
    } // end userNumber array populating

    for (int outerloop = 0; outerloop < userNumber.length; outerloop++){
        for (int innerloop = outerloop - 1; innerloop > -1; innerloop --){
            while (userNumber[outerloop] == userNumber [innerloop]){
            System.out.println("user compare: " + outerloop + " with: " + innerloop);
            } // end while loop
        }// end inner loop
    } // end outer loop

    return userNumber;
} // end getUserNumberDebugMode
```

Comment: This is difficult to read, and also difficult to understand what you're asking for.  What exactly isn't working?  What are you seeing vs. what do you expect?  What have you already tried?

Comment: At the moment it is infinitely looping when it finds two digits the same. If the user enters 323 for instance, it should ask the user for a number with unique digits, like 326, and then put the digits into an array and check again.

Comment: I've solved the problem but can't post my solution til later. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have solved the problem by clocking up a unique number check if any of the numbers match, and then putting the whole thing in a do/while loop while the unique number check > 0. Not the most elegant fix I'm sure, but it works and it'll do.

```
do{
        uniqueCheck = 0;
        userGuessAsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(compNum + "\n Please enter a number.");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(userGuessAsString);

    // put three digit number individually into array
    for(int loop = (userNumber.length - 1); loop>=0; loop--){
        userNumber[loop]= number%10;
        number = number/10;
    } // end userNumber array populating

    for (int loop = 0; loop < userNumber.length; loop++){
        for(int innerLoop  = 0; innerLoop < userNumber.length; innerLoop++) {
            if(loop != innerLoop) {
                if (userNumber[loop] == userNumber[innerLoop] ){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter three unique digits!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    uniqueCheck ++;
                } //  end inner IF loop
            } // end outer IF loop
        } // end inner for loop
    } // end outer for loop

    } while (uniqueCheck > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt go through the program since it looks a little complex for what you want to achieve. To ensure that the user enters a number with 3 unique digits, try this algorithm:

1. Split the characters in the string the user has entered.
2. Convert each character into an integer and put it into a Set.
3. While adding it into a Set ensure that set.add() returns true.
4. If it does not then the digits are not unique and you can throw an error and get the data again from the user.
5. Else go ahead with the comparison with the computer generated number.

Much simpler, rather than looping.

Comment: +1 for mentioning sets -- absolutely the right data structure for checking uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

well, you probably don't want that innermost "while" loop, as that will just run forever as soon as you get a matching value.

however, concerning your outerloop and innerloop values, the first time you check userNumber, `outerloop` will be `0` and `innerloop` will be `-1`.  probably not what you want.  in order to get your loop logic correct, just step through each line of code determining what each variable will be at each step (or do this in a debugger).  that should help you correct your logic.

Answer (score 0):

As homework assistance, I'm going to suggest that you're looking at this the wrong way. Bear in mind that mistakes in approach can lead you to triply-nested loops and O(n^2) or worse when an O(n) solution is available.

It sounds like you're not looking for a 3-digit number, you're looking for 3 digits - these are very different things - if order doesn't matter, make that fact work for you. If you're just looking for X digits and verifying for each one after the first that it hasn't been seen more than N times (here N=0), then you've chosen the wrong thing to make into an array.

You should be able to do this with no nested loops. If you're careful I believe you should be able to do it with only a single loop (assuming that arrays initialize to something sane or that you can check whether cells are initialized). If you're just a little more clever you can probably make your solution to this work correctly for the next problem, involving 10 unique digits, or digits being seen no more than 3 times, or expanding to include letters.

Put differently, are you doing a bubble sort on this? To determine whether the value at position Y has been seen before are you iterating through positions 0 to Y-1? Are you then repeating that at position Y+1 by going through 0 to Y?

Comment: It needs to be in an array so that it can be checked against the computer number for numbers that match in position and numbers that are within the three digits but not in the right position, eg. 326 compared with 367 would give one 'bullseye', the 3, and one 'hit', the 6. I've got that working, just not the user validation. To start off with the user had to enter one number at a time, but the spec states the user needs to be able to put in a 3 digit number at a time.

Comment: OK, I wasn't thinking in terms of a Mastermind implementation. There's been quite a bit of focus on optimal solutions for that category of problems, but for something like this I'd still say you're looking at the wrong array - don't use an array of positions storing digits, use an array of digits storing positions. (If you're not familiar with Mastermind, just search for "Mastermind game")